# ¿Cómo incrementar input_vars en App Service de Azure?

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

Estoy usando el tema Avada para crear un sitio en WordPress, debe estar en un App Service de Azure.

El estado del sistema me sugiere incrementar PHP Max Input Vars a 1500, pero no encuentro cómo hacerlo en un App Service.

He intentado creando un archivo `php.ini` con la instrucción `max_input_vars = 1500;`

También he visto que se puede hacer desde el `.htaccess`, pero creo que no tiene sentido ya que no está corriendo en Apache.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible cambiar `max_input_vars`creando un archivo `php.ini` con la instrucción `max_input_vars = 1500;` pero colocandolo en el directorio `wp-admin`

Comment: Si esto responde a tu pregunta, recuerda [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.